Group and concatenate columns in power query
I want to get this result in power query from the first to the second which concatenates and group columns at the same time.
Thank you for your help.


Try
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Item", "Description"}, {
    {"Qty", each List.Sum([Qty]), type number},
    {"lots", each Text.Combine(Table.AddColumn(_, "Custom", each Text.From([Lot])&"("&Text.From([Qty])&")")[Custom],","), type text}
})
in  #"Grouped Rows"



Hi there, awesome !!! That simple? Thanks a lot.

Everything is simple if you know how to do it! Feel free to upvote using arrow atop question mark if you think this would help someone else

Sorry unsure of your request. Please start your own question

Nope. Sorry no idea
